About writing/reading "\r\n" to/from a file
Why, if you write a string containing  "\r\n"  to a file opened in binary mode, and then read that string from the same file, but opened in text mode, then the string will  contain '\n' instead оf "\r\n" ?
The code is:
std::ofstream out_file("1.txt", std::ios::binary);
out_file.write("0\r1\r\n2", 6);
out_file.close();
std::ifstream in_file("1.txt");
std::string   txt{ std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in_file),
                   std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() };

std::cout << "txt.size() = " << txt.size() <<  '\n';
for (int i = 0; i < txt.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "i = " << i << " char code = " << int(txt[i]) << '\n';
}

I tested on Windows (g++, clang, msvc)
Addition
Thanks everyone for the answer and comments!
I found experimentally, that '\n’ convert  to '\r\n' on output only if std::ios::binary is used, and '\r\n' convert to '\n' on input only if std::ios::binary is not used.
Why this particular logic is implemented is completely unclear :)

When you read a file as text, the OS might modify the end-of-line charater(s) according to its convention.

Reading tutorial like Binary and text modes is always successful study technique.

Line ending in text mode depends on your OS. Any compiler you use, has target OS configurations. On UNIX, you have a '\n' as the eol, on dos/windows it's '\r' followed by '\n' and on apple OS it is '\n' then '\r'. Text mode read/writes always turn eol into single '\n'.

The specifics to answer your question vary between operating systems, since different OSs (and, in some cases, different disk I/O drivers or subsystems) have different conventions.  Under windows the convention is that a "text" file is stored on disk with ends of lines marked by a "\r\n" pair.   When opening a file stream for writing in "text" mode, a '\n' written to the stream is translated into a "\r\n" pair and that is actually written (e.g. to disk)..   The reverse translation is done when reading a file opened in "text" mode.    In binary mode, there is no such translation.

Because (on Windows) that's how text mode and binary mode work. In text mode native line endings are translated into '\n'. In binary mode that aren't. Not sure why you are puzzled by this.

@Red.Wave The old Mac convention hasn't been in use since System 9, over two decades ago.

@molbdnilo good to know. But it's still an available convention.

Newlines galore!  ASCII (1963-1968) 0D0A or 0A0D, ASCII 1968- the 0D becomes optional, ISO 0A or 0D0A, MS-DOS thru Windows 11 0D0A (from Q-DOS, from CP/M), EBCDIC 15, AppleDOS thru Mac OS 9 0D, Multics/Unix/Linux/Mac OS X/macOS 0A, ECMA-94 85, QNX (pre-POSIX) 1E, ZX80 & ZX81 76, Pick/BASIC 1F.  And Unicode U+2028 and U+2029.  TSO/ISPF had fixed line lengths (typically 72 or 80, specified as metadata for the text file), so the newline was not encoded in the file.

"Why this particular logic is implemented is completely unclear :)" -- well, if you want a binary file of 1 byte containing just 0x0A (\n), you don't want 2 bytes to be written. So you need a way of writing single bytes and that's binary mode.

The std::ios_base::openmode documentation for std::ios::binary refers to the std::FILE documentation for binary and text modes.
This means that the rules that govern the bahvior of C file streams is also applicable to std::ofstream and std::ifstream.
Specifically the documentation for binary and text modes states that:

A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters that can be
composed into lines; a line can be decomposed into zero or more
characters plus a terminating '\n' (“newline”) character. Whether the
last line requires a terminating '\n' is implementation-defined.
Furthermore, characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on
input and output to conform to the conventions for representing text
in the OS (in particular, C streams on Windows OS convert '\n' to
'\r\n' on output, and convert '\r\n' to '\n' on input).

(emphasis in mine)
Therefore since you are on Windows, text streams convert '\r\n' to '\n' on input.

Thank you very much for your answer! I found experimentally, that '\n’ convert  to '\r\n' on output only if std::ios::binary is used, and '\r\n' convert to '\n' on input only if std::ios::binary is not used.
Why this particular logic is implemented is completely unclear :)

@Pavel each OS has its own convention for end-of-line character(s) in text files. This is explained in the links in my answer. If it solves your issue you can consider to click '✔' (below the score) to mark it as an accepted answer. You can also consider to upvote (accepting and voting is totally separate, you can do both). See: What should I do when someone answers my question?.
